# CF9: what is jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll intended for?

Tags: coldfusion, jrun

I just finished installing an application on a server running ColdFusion 9 (2008 R2 64bit)

The application I installed does not use CF, but an isapi dll.

To run my application, I need to delete an handler using jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll that seems to process and block requests that should be processed by my isapi dll.

I do not known Cold Fusion, but I'm curious:
what is jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll intended for?

thank you in advance

stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the ISAPI filter connector files between IIS and the JRun server that ColdFusion sits on top of.  IIS hands off requests to the ISAPI filter for processing, which funnels them to JRun, which in turn hands them to ColdFusion to execute.  If your site is not running any ColdFusion files (.cfm files) then you can safely remove that ISAPI filter from that web site in IIS.